# Building HighCharts-Export Server 2.1 Fails

Tags: java, maven, highcharts

I have downloaded the latest highcharts-exporter following the instructions [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/java). I am running this on Windows7 x64 locally and it will eventually be in a Windows production environment using Jetty9.

I have changed one line in highcharts-export/src/main/resources/app.properties:

```
# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
exec = /Scripts/phantomjs
```

I have maven (3.0.5) installed and configured. I last built this project before the 3.x release of HighCharts. That build was successful.

When I try to build now I get the following output. Any info here would be great.

**EDIT**

It appears that these errors are caused by left over files from previous version of highcharts-export. I have done a complete clean of the entire directory to start fresh. I am still getting one error that makes it not build:

```
C:\hc-exporter>mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
com.highcharts.export:highcharts-export:war:2.0.1
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ecli
pse-plugin is missing. @ line 150, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t
he stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin
g such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building highcharts-export 2.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ highcharts-export --
-
[INFO] Deleting C:\hc-exporter\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ highcharts
-export ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ highcharts-ex
port ---
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files to C:\hc-exporter\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\pool\ServerObjectFact
ory.java:[68,29] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.652s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 16 13:53:36 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
5.1:compile (default-compile) on project highcharts-export: Compilation failure
[ERROR] C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\pool\ServerObjectFact
ory.java:[68,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
C:\hc-exporter>
```

Old errors - just here for reference.

> C:\hc-exporter>mvn -version Apache Maven 3.0.5
>   (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 08:51: 28-0500)
>   Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.5 Java version: 1.7.0_10, vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 7",
>   version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows" C:\hc-exporter>mvn
>   clean package [INFO] Scanning for projects... [WARNING] [WARNING] Some
>   problems were encountered while building the effective model for
>   com.highcharts.export:highcharts-export:war:2.0.1 [WARNING]
>   'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ecli
>   pse-plugin is missing. @ line 150, column 12 [WARNING] [WARNING] It is
>   highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t he
>   stability of your build. [WARNING] [WARNING] For this reason, future
>   Maven versions might no longer support buildin g such malformed
>   projects. [WARNING] [INFO] [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building highcharts-export 2.0.1 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @
>   highcharts-export --
>   - [INFO] Deleting C:\hc-exporter\target [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ highcharts
>   -export --- [debug] execute contextualize [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 2 resources [INFO]
>   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @
>   highcharts-ex port --- [INFO] Compiling 16 source files to
>   C:\hc-exporter\target\classes [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[8,34] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder does not exist
>   [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[9,34] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder does not exist
>   [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[10,34] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder does not exist
>   [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[11,34] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder does not exist
>   [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[12,40] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder.image does not
>   exist [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[13,40] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder.image does not
>   exist [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[14,25] error: package org.apache.fop.svg does not exist [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[32,34] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class
>   TranscoderException   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[63,1
>   5] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class
>   SVGAbstractTranscoder   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\pool\ServerObjectFactory.java
>   :[68,29] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   variable ACTIVE
>   location: class ServerState
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[34,2
>   ] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class TranscoderInput 
>   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[34,3
>   0] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class TranscoderInput
>   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[35,2
>   ] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class TranscoderOutput
>   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[35,3
>   7] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class
>   TranscoderOutput   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[37,2
>   ] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class
>   SVGAbstractTranscoder   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[45,3
>   3] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   variable
>   SVGAbstractTranscoder   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[53,3
>   4] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   variable
>   SVGAbstractTranscoder   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[66,2
>   ] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class
>   SVGAbstractTranscoder   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[70,2
>   0] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class PNGTranscoder
>   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[73,2
>   0] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class JPEGTranscoder 
>   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[74,3
>   3] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   variable
>   JPEGTranscoder   location: class SVGRasterizer
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.java:[78,2
>   0] error: cannot find symbol [INFO] 22 errors [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 7.741s [INFO] Finished at: Thu May 16 12:54:29 EDT
>   2013 [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/122M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
>   5.1:compile (default-compile) on project highcharts-export: Compilation failure:  Compilation failure: [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[8,34] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder does not exist
>   [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[9,34] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder does not exist
>   [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[10,34] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder does not exist
>   [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[11,34] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder does not exist
>   [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[12,40] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder.image does not
>   exist [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[13,40] error: package org.apache.batik.transcoder.image does not
>   exist [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[14,25] error: package org.apache.fop.svg does not exist [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[32,34] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   TranscoderException [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[63,15] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   SVGAbstractTranscoder [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\pool\ServerObjectFact
>   ory.java:[68,29] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   variable
>   ACTIVE [ERROR] location: class ServerState [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[34,2] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   TranscoderInput [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[34,30] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   TranscoderInput [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[35,2] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   TranscoderOutput [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[35,37] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   TranscoderOutput [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[37,2] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   SVGAbstractTranscoder [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[45,33] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   variable
>   SVGAbstractTranscoder [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[53,34] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   variable
>   SVGAbstractTranscoder [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[66,2] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   SVGAbstractTranscoder [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[70,20] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   PNGTranscoder [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[73,20] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   JPEGTranscoder [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[74,33] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   variable
>   JPEGTranscoder [ERROR] location: class SVGRasterizer [ERROR]
>   C:\hc-exporter\src\main\java\com\highcharts\export\util\SVGRasterizer.ja
>   va:[78,20] error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e swit ch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable
>   full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the
>   errors and possible solutions, please rea d the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc eption
>   C:\hc-exporter>

Comment: @wergeId I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @jvallver, not yet. This is a huge delay for us.

Comment: @jvallver, I have opened up an issue on their github. Issue #1854.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem.

[zhiweihu](https://github.com/zhiweihu) has upload a [patch](https://github.com/zhiweihu/highcharts.com/commit/df455d7651cb4bf81b4d6d9f3e3600d4cc9f712e) that solves the issue. The problem is that `ServerState` class do not have the `ACTIVE` state.

Once you have applied the [patch](https://github.com/zhiweihu/highcharts.com/commit/df455d7651cb4bf81b4d6d9f3e3600d4cc9f712e), you can create the package without a problem and it works as expected.

Comment: Build succeeded. Testing now.

Comment: Well, it builds but I am getting 503 - Service Unavailable when I try and call it from my code using localhost Jetty install

Comment: Error on jetty when loading this WAR: Error creating bean with name 'serverObjectFactory': Invocation of init method failed. Then the ubiquitous stack dump.

Comment: I wonder if highcharts-export is expecting linux-style path for phantomjs? My app.properties file has this: `# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
exec = C:\\jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3\\webapps\\ROOT\\Scripts\\phantomjs`

Comment: Be sure you have set the `script` property correctly in the `app.properties` file. It has to have the path to `highcharts-convert.js` file

Comment: I use both the windows and linux environment for deploying the highcharts-export server. I always use forward slashes for both environments.

Comment: @gertvaartjes, So I would do this instead: `C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs` ?

Comment: @jvallver, I am using the default so it should be `/WEB-INF/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js` if left blank. Issue is what to put in ofr the phantomjs executable.

Comment: @wergeId but if you read the comment "... This is tested in TOMCAT, but specify a path if resource loading isn't working with the classloader (f.e. with Jetty server), script = a/path/to/my/phantomjs-script." It says that if you are using Jetty you have to set this property.

Comment: @jvallver, That's right. By the way, I would add PhantomJS to the PATH. Then you could use phantoms as exec variable.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been fixed in the Highcharts repository on [Github](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/java/). So you won't need the patch anymore, just pull in the changes